# Javascript - how to update elements inner html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like this:

```
var stopwatch = function (item) {
   window.setInterval(function () {
                item.innerHtml = myInteger++;
        }, 1000);
}
```

This code was supposed to display `myInteger`, but it is not updating values of `item`. Why (`item` is a div with text inside)?

Comment: Name of the property is `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`. Supposing `item` is a DOM Element object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There could be a lot of reasons (we need to see more of your code), but here is a working example:

```
var myInteger = 1,
stopwatch = function (item) {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        item.innerHTML = myInteger++;
    }, 1000);
}
stopwatch(document.querySelector('div'));
```

Important changes:

- Calling `stopwatch` (you probably do this)
- `- innerHtml` `+innerHTML` (the case matters).  You won't get an error for setting `innerHtml`; it will set that property and you won't notice anything.
- Initialize `myInteger`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4krM/

Comment: I have basically the same code as you do, yet it still doesn't work for me... I hate javascript with every inch of my body..

Comment: @ojek can you create an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Dude don't tell me this works... It is not working on my site, ffs... Now I think that this is because the windows that I am using this on, is dynamically created? Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var stopwatch = setInterval(function (item) {
    item.innerHtml = myInteger++;
}, 1000);
```

This should work